# jQuery append DM event no longer works

Tags: jquery, dom, append

I appreciate that this questino has been asked before, I have trawled the answers on StackOverFlow but none of the solutions work in my case.

Simple setup:

I have a row of boxes, when you mouse over and away from a box an alert appears. Click the text to clear the div and make a new box. The new box won't respond to the mouseover.

I know this has something to do with DOM events and page loads but I just cannot find a solution.

I am using:

```
$('.box').on('mouseenter', function(){});
```

I have also tried using .live

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/d2PWH/3/

Thank you in advance.

ALan.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Always include **all** the relevant code and markup **in** the question, don't just link, not even to jsFiddle. The question becomes meaningless if jsFiddle goes away, and regardless people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Event delegation! Target an element that exists on load!

```
$(".row").on("mouseenter", ".box", function() {
```

Comment: @AlanA: If this *answered* your question, the way SO works, you'd "accept" the answer by clicking the empty checkmark next to it. More in the help center.